# TextButton's text Not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am making my first app for android in jetpack compose. I am trying to make a text button that will update it's text each time it is pressed, however while it is showing just fine on the device it does not update the Button

```
@Composable
fun ShotButton(){
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf("N") }
    TextButton(modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp, height = 70.dp),onClick = {
        if(state == "N") state = "Y"
        if(state == "Y") state = "R"
        if(state == "R") state = "N"

    }) {
        Text(text = state, fontSize = 60.sp)
    }
}
```

I have done many changes to how i declare the button and the state variable, and the documentation doesn't really clear my doubts

Comment: You are not returning from the onClick function after setting the state. Therefore, first, you're setting the state to Y. Then, the second 'if' will be true, setting the state to R. After that, the last 'if' will also be true, and the state will be set to N. Consequently, it will seem like the state never changed. You can use 'else if' or a switch statement, like 'when'.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `when` to check different state condition like this:

```
onClick = {
    when(state) {
        "N" -> state = "Y"
        "Y" -> state = "R"
        "R" -> state = "N"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `when`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ShotButton() {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf("N") }
    TextButton(modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp, height = 70.dp), onClick = {
        when (state) {
            "N" -> state = "Y"
            "Y" -> state = "R"
            "R" -> state = "N"
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = state, fontSize = 60.sp)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because all your if conditions are getting executed.

You can use else-if :

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ShotButton(){
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf("N") }
    TextButton(modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp, height = 70.dp),onClick = {
        if(state == "N") {
            state = "Y"
        } else if(state == "Y") {
            state = "R"
        } else if(state == "R") {
            state = "N"
        }

    }) {
        Text(text = state, fontSize = 60.sp)
    }
}
```

or replace them by a `when`